# Persist Strapi SQLite Database on Azure App Service Linux host from Docker Container

Tags: azure, sqlite, docker-compose, strapi, azure-web-app-for-containers

I'm trying to persist a Strapi SQLite database on an Azure App Service Linux host from a docker container.

I've tried using the two methods below:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container#use-persistent-shared-storage
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-linux

Both are resulting the below error:

```
2020-08-30T01:48:39.664184204Z [2020-08-30T01:48:39.664Z] error Error: create table `core_store` (`id` integer not null primary key autoincrement, `key` varchar(255) null, `value` text null, `type` varchar(255) null, `environment` varchar(255) null, `tag` varchar(255) null) - SQLITE_BUSY: database is locked
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  cms:
     image: myacr.azurecr.io/repo:latest-dev
     volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot/dbstore:/cms/data
     ports:
       - "80:1337"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems it's the problem of the SQLite Database, not the Azure App service. And moreover, the Azure Web App only exposes the port 80 and 443. So you need to map your port of the container you need to the port 80 or 443.

Comment: Right. I just didn't know if there was anything special I needed to set in the Azure Storage Account File System or `/home` directory to make SQLite happy. I've been able to persist the `/cms/data` using `docker volumes`, but, as far as I know those aren't available via Azure App Service. Will change the published port. Thanks!

Comment: @Cole Docker volume does not persist data. So it just can be used for the test. And if it works for you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Cole Any more updates for the question? Does it solve your problem?